# Reading package error with apt-get command

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, updates, dpkg

Every time I am using apt-get update command I am getting this error.

```
Reading package lists... Error!
W: The repository 'http://php53.dotdeb.org stable Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/php53.dotdeb.org_dists_stable_all_binary-amd64_Packages
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

I tried the following command

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo apt-get update
```

but `apt-get update` command gives same error.